# Links not rendering in RSpec feature spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, bootstrap-4, capybara

The following code is supposed to render some links, but when doing a feature spec in RSpec to test it the links are not present when doing `save_and_open_screenshot` even after doing a long sleep they still won't show up. Doing `save_and_open_page` does show the links are present.

```
%nav#sidebar
  = form_with url: entries_path, local: true, method: :get do |f|
    = f.text_field :search
    = button_tag type: 'submit' do
      %i.fas.fa-search
  %ul.nav.flex-column.pb-5.mb-5
    - months.each do |month|
      %li.nav-item
        .nav-link{class: (current_page?(entries_path(month: month.to_date)) && 'active')}
          = link_to month.strftime('%b-%Y'), entries_path(month: month.to_date)
```

CSS on the sidebar:

```
@import 'bootstrap'
@import 'fontawesome'

#sidebar
  padding: 10px 0 30px 0
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd
  width: 200px
  border-radius: 0 0 0 4px
  transition: margin .3s

  @include media-breakpoint-down(md)
    position: absolute
    top: 0
    bottom: 0
    z-index: 9
    margin-left: -200px

    &.visible
      margin-left: 0

  .nav-link
    @extend .d-flex
    @extend .align-items-center
    height: 40px
    padding: 0 30px

    &.active
      position: relative
      font-weight: bold
```

I'm also using turbolinks on this project, don't know if that might be interfering in any way with the rendering of the links in the spec.

Comment: Since there are links present in the HTML, but not visible in a screenshot that means they're being hidden via CSS - At what level does the content disappear, ie - is the #sidebar element visible in the screenshot? what about the form? , etc -- figure out what the highest level element being hidden is and check the CSS on it.

Comment: You might also want to switch over to running chrome non-headless temporarily so you can watch the test run, and inspect the page in the browsers developer console by pausing the test when you think the links should be visible.  Also, deleting your previous questions when they've been answered kind of goes against the idea of SO since it's taking away knowledge other people may later need.

Comment: If the links are visible in `save_and_open_page` then the links are present on the page. You might need to change your selectors/matchers to assert the links.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I deleted the previous question because it was wrong and had no answers on it yet. If it had any answers I wouldn't have done so. I'll give what you suggested a try, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `margin-left: -200px` in the `@include media-breakpoint-down(md)` section looks like the probable culprit.  Given specific screen sizes (not determinable what those are from what you've posted) the sidebar would be hidden off the left edge of the screen (and therefore non-visible).  You probably need to set the window size of the browser correctly for the tests you're running.